# Scala function arguments: class vs function generic type, e.g. f(classOf[Foo], "bar") vs f[Foo]("bar")

Tags: scala, class, generics, implicit

In Scala is it common practice to pass in class types as generics or explicitly pass them in?

For example I have created a helper function to create a Java object that takes in a source exception, target exception and a third parameter (I'll just use a String for this example). Which one is better practice in Scala:

```
exceptionTranslation(classOf[FooException], classOf[BarException], "blah")

def exceptionTranslation(sourceClazz: Class[_ <: Throwable], targetClazz: Class[_ <: Throwable], message: String) = new Translation()
  .withSource(sourceClazz)
  .withTarget(targetClazz)
  .withMessage(message)
```

Or

```
exceptionTranslation[FooException, BarException]("blah")

def exceptionTranslation[Source <: Throwable, Target <: Throwable](message: String)(
implicit source: ClassTag[Source], target: ClassTag[Target]) = new Translation()
  .withSource(source.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Source]])
  .withTarget(target.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Target]])
  .withMessage(message)
```

Comment: I like the first one better as you don't need any implicits and runtime casting, but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Agree with @Tuval, the second one is absolutely overkill

Answer (score 1):

I think is just a matter of style. They are all correct. Personally, I would go with the one that is more intuitive, shorter, and has the least power.

Example of extracting the text name of a class:

```
import scala.reflect._
def bar[F](x: Class[F]) = x.getName

def foo[X:ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[X]].runtimeClass.getName

def foobar[X](implicit ctag: ClassTag[X]) = ctag.runtimeClass.getName
```

Usage:

```
> bar(classOf[Double]) // This one has better Java interop 
res: String = "double"

> foo[Double]  // This looks slightly less verbose when calling 
res: String = "double"

> foobar[Double]
res: String = "double"
```

Comment: The function was private and for me it felt weird using the generic types of the function to pass in parameters however it read much cleaner when calling the function (the "foo" or "foobar" way). Since most people would be reading the list of exception translations and never really looking at the private helper function, I figured simplifying the calls to the function was more important.